# 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, python-3.10

I have a bot on discord and when i start the host, i get this message repeatable "403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user". What should I do. I will let the main.py code here. I have a folder with commands also that runs on a bot, if that code from above is looking alright, I can give you the others.

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from readsettings import ReadSettings
from command_handler import CommandHander
import time
import functions as Functions

settings = ReadSettings('settings.json')
commandHandler = None

class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents = discord.Intents.all())
        self.synced = False
        self.started = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id=settings['Discord_Guild_ID']))
            self.synced = True
        print(f"Logged into bot account: {self.user}.")
        commandHandler.initialize()
        await Functions.sendLogToChannel(client, f'{settings["Bot_Name"]} Started!', f'{settings["Bot_Name"]} has successfully started!', 0x00ff00, tag=True)
        
client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
commandHandler = CommandHander(client, tree, settings)`
client.run(settings['Bot_Token'])
```

Comment: Where exactly are you sending a DM to a user? It's not very apparent here. Either way, put a try-except around it. Users can disable their DM's, and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: The bot sent the dm privately. The things is that on the host, this message repeat every time, idk if i can attach screenshots here

Comment: Well yes it's a DM, it's obviously sent privately, that's what a DM literally is. I'm asking for the line of code that triggered it. And once again, just put a try-except around it.

Comment: On another note, people find getting random DM's from bots really annoying (which is why they're disabled), and sending too many of them will get you ratelimited. Consider if you really need this.